# How to change dimensions of an object proportionally?

Tags: modeling, workflow, objects, dimensions

I need to change the 3 dimensions of an object, but only by changing one dimension.

That is, if the object has the following dimensions:

- height: 2 units (Z)
- width: 0.5 units (Y)
- depth: 0.1 units (X)

When I change the height of 2 units to 3 units, then the other width dimensions (Y) and depth (X) should automatically change to 0.75 and 0.15 respectively.

I do this by scaling (<kbd>S</kbd>):

1. I press the <kbd>S</kbd> key
2. I press the <kbd>=</kbd> key
3. After Income Division 3/2. 3 is the new dimension and 2 above.

But I would like to know if there is a better way to do so through the properties panel (<kbd>N</kbd>).
The options in the properties panel, when I change the height of 2 units to 3 units, the width and depth do not change.

Comment: For now I think your current approach is the best way of doing this. This should be possible with multi number button editing in the future, but there is currently [a bug](https://developer.blender.org/T38587) preventing this.

Answer (score 3):

There is a solution since version 2.70:
[http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Dev:Ref/Release_Notes/2.70/UI#Multi-Number_Button_Editing](http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Dev%3aRef/Release_Notes/2.70/UI#Multi-Number_Button_Editing)

Click and drag from the first to the last fields you want to edit and release the click. The three fields are highlighted. Enter an expression, eg. *3/2 and press enter. All fields are edited at the same time.

Comment: Unfortunately it doesn't quite work that way, all the selected number buttons will be changed the final result of the button being edited. This is a [known limitation](https://developer.blender.org/D270#comment-15). Also note that if you want to do this on the dimensions, there is [known bug](https://developer.blender.org/T38587) with that too.

Comment: Dragging vertically down across all 3 axis fields, then moving horizontally across the bottom one alters all 3 fields proportionally and works for every build I've tried for a couple months now.

Comment: @MarcClintDion By god you're right!  Haha, I was blown away for a second when I tried this and realized it works.  But then I realized that you get the same result, and a little bit more elegantly, by just pressing S.  Cheers ;)